# DDD, Microservices and data direction

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

Let's assume I have Identity Management bounded context and discussion bounded context. Each of those is a separate micro service.

Identity has Users, Discussion has Moderators.

If I update first and last name in the Identity bounded context, my plan is to publish a message to Amazon SQS, and have discussion bounded context to listen that queue for any changes, and update first and last name in discussion context via Anti-Corruption layer.

My question is, what if I decide to change first name and last name in the Discussion BC? Should my Identity BS listen for that changes too, or having bi-directional communication is not considered a good practice, and I should always update that information inside Identity BC?

Comment: What do you think about having the name fully owned in one BC and have the other BC have a "reference ID" only, and then have a composite UI show everything together?

Comment: Currently planing only services architecture, without any UI. Consumers could be 3rd party companies and our company.  If I use only reference id, wouldn't that mean that Discussion BC will not have necessary data in it's domain, and will be heavily dependable on Identity BC?

Comment: What functionality in the Discussion BC requires the data referred to by the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should my Identity BS listen for that changes too, or having bi-directional communication is not considered a good practice

I don't think bi-directional communication is necessarily the problem here.  What concerns me is that you seem to have two different BCs acting as the "book of record" for identity.

In the [blue book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), Evans writes of bounded contexts being defined by meaning; when you cross from one context to another, you may need to change your understanding of what is understood by the common terminology: it doesn't necessarily follow that the rules for an aggregate in one context (User?) will be the same as in another.

The given example, User, is potentially more twitchy - because it may be that the real world, rather than the model, is the book of record, and the "aggregate" is really just a dumb bag of data.

> If I use only reference id, wouldn't that mean that Discussion BC will not have necessary data in its domain

Necessary for what?  Do changes in the discussion book of record depend on data stored in the Identity book of record?

> Example for, in identity context i have user with username, first name and last name etc, but in discussion context I might have that same user but represented as moderator or poster with only necessary properties for that BC. If name changes in the identity context, it should propagate that changes to discussion.

That sounds as though you are describing it as necessary for your *reads*; as though you have a view of a discussion that includes a representation of the participants that includes their roles (which exist in the discussion BC) and their identities.

Reads tend not to be a very interesting use case, because reads don't change the book of record.  As Udi hinted at, to build the view you basically need a reference id that you can use to pull the data you want out of some key value store.  Is there any reason to prefer that the KV store is part of *this* BC as opposed to *that* one?

> Consumers could be 3rd party companies and our company.

Connecting to the microservice(s) directly, or instead consuming an api that acts as a facade for the backing micro services?

Comment: Example for, in identity context i have user with username, first name and last name etc, but in discussion context I might have that same user but represented as moderator or poster with only necessary properties for that BC. If name changes in the identity context, it should propagate that changes to discussion. We are still discussing should we allow direct access, or should it be facade in front.

Answer (score 2):

How do people change their names?

I would try and have a single place where this is allowed, and have that context own the data. Other context can then subscribe to changes and act accordingly.

Comment: so If an admin decided to add a new Moderator, he will first be created inside Identity BC, and discussion BC will copy needed data in order to create a Moderator. Same goes for the updates? Always do it via Identity BC endpoints?

Comment: It's difficult to provide exact answers without knowing the domain a lot better. It just seems simpler to me to have a single place where you manage users. If your other contexts then subscribe to changes you can do what you want in them. Does the Identity context need to know when someone becomes a Moderator, or is that only a concern of the Discussion BC?